# Backbone simply add variable in event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How to add variable of element to any event? I want to do something like this:
HTML code:

```
 <ul id="ul">
     <li>
      <a href="#" id="first">First</a>
      <a href="#" id="second">Second</a>
      <a href="#" id="third">Third</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#" id="dont-need-to-work">Fourth</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

And js:

```
    var Any = Backbone.View.extend({
      events: {
        'click '+this.$el.find('a'): function (e) {
          this.anyAction(e);
        }
      },

      anyAction: function (event) {
          console.log($( event.currentTarget ).attr('id'))
      }

    });

    var view = new Any({
      el: 'ul#ul',
    })
```

I found some options, most with _events, but I need to send event to method.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bd3dQ/ 
this is my example that doesn't work )

Comment: You want to attach the `anyAction` callback for a `click` event to all the `<a>` tags in your view?

Comment: In this case I want to attach it to all children <a> of <ul id="ul">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ad function name to event and change selector in events:

```
  events: {
    'click a': 'anyAction'
  },

  anyAction: function (event) {
      console.log($( event.currentTarget ).attr('id'))
  }
```

Comment: This would catch all a-clicks in document which might be a bad idea, if there are other links in the page at the same time.

Comment: No, it catch all click only in view element. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Bd3dQ/1/

Comment: True, but it might still have some unwanted effects.

Comment: in Backbone View is defined reference to element ul#ul named this.el orthis.$el for jquery object.  When add events backbone using selector simmilar to $el.find('a').on('click', ...), and $el is refrence to ul#ul.

Answer (score 1):

You should ad a class to those html elements like this:

```
<ul id="ul">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="elemToClick" id="first">First</a>
        <a href="#" class="elemToClick" id="second">Second</a>
        <a href="#" class="elemToClick" id="third">Third</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And in your view attach a listener to that *class*

```
events: {
    'click .elemToClick': 'anyAction'
}
```

Comment: Oh... this is so much better than my suggestion... +1

Comment: No, it is understandible. But I have variable var el = #ul. This code should work inside each ul container separately.

Comment: Realy, is there no solution to simple add variable in event?

Comment: @SergeyKudryashov - you can just expand the selector then:  `'click #ul.elemToClick': 'anyAction'`